# What's wrong with my file check script?

Tags: bash, files, directory, test

I don't understand why the last part of my script does not display anything when no file or directory is found.

```
echo -n "Please enter a filename or directory: "
read filename
if [ -z "$filename" ]; then
  echo "You did not enter anything!"
  exit 1
fi
if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
  if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    echo "You entered a file."
  elif [ -d "$filename" ]; then
    echo "You entered a directory."
  else
    echo "You did not enter a valid file or directory."
  fi
fi
exit
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. It will not display the echo if an invalid or nonexistent file or directory is inputted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I re-formatted your script to indent the `if` statements. Doing so made it clearer that your last `echo` only happens if `-f` is true and `-d` is false. If the user enters a file or directory that doesn't exist, then `-f` fails.

Consider this revision to your last section:

```
if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
  if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    echo "You entered a file."
  elif [ -d "$filename" ]; then
    echo "You entered a directory."
  fi
else
  echo "You did not enter a valid file or directory."
fi
```

Where the true section of the first `if` statement is ended earlier (by `else`); then files/directories that don't exist have a section of code to execute.

Comment: Still trying to comprehend this. So my order is wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say the *order* was wrong so much as the logic. See my recent edit for code & explanation.

Comment: I see. Just one of those things I overlooked, but makes a big difference. Good eye Jeff thanks.

Comment: in other words, you have nested `if` statements, so you have to make sure that the `elif`s and `else`s and `fi`s match up to the correct nesting level. extra  indentation per level is a good way to help see that.

Comment: It's easy to get lost in deeply-nested statements, which is why the first thing I wanted to do was edit your code to indent it. Another thing I'll do when writing code where I know nested statement are coming is to write the "structure" (if/elif/else/fi) in direct sequence, so that I know which section deals with what, then go fill in the blanks.

Comment: btw, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832899/proper-indentation-of-bash-script

Comment: This code prints nothing when the filename is `/dev/tty`.

Answer (score 3):

There are many other types of files that will not cause any output in this code.  These include symbolic links, named pipes, sockets, and block and character special files.  Notably, `/dev/tty`, `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` fall through, undetected by the code.

You could modify the logic to account for this, however, this structure (case statement style structure) is easier to read and less error-prone:

```
if [ ! -e "$filename" ]; then
    echo "$filename does not exist"
    exit 1
elif [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    echo "You entered a file."
elif [ -d "$filename" ]; then
    echo "You entered a directory."
else 
    echo "$filename is not a regular file or directory."
    exit 2
fi
```